# Debug .Net Core Console App out of Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I want to run and debug a .Net Core (2.2) Console application (not ASP.Net Core!).
Therefore, I've created a very simple app:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WriteLine("**Environment**");
        WriteLine($"Platform: .NET Core");
        WriteLine($"OS: {RuntimeInformation.OSDescription}");
        WriteLine();
        ReadLine();
    }

    private static (string, bool) ParseArgs(string[] args)
    {
        var buffer = new StringBuilder();
        var withColor = false;
        foreach (var s in args)
        {
            if (s == "--with-color")
            {
                withColor = true;
                continue;
            }
            buffer.Append(" ");
            buffer.Append(s);
        }

        return (buffer.ToString(), withColor);
    }
}
```

Added a Docker file.

Added the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets` NuGet package.

Finaly changed the `launchSettings.json` to:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "dotnetapp": {
      "commandName": "Project"
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker"
    }
  }
}
```

So everything looks like in a default ASP.Net Core WebApp with docker support.

But on "run" I only get a error "The profile 'Docker' can not be executed with this application".

I don't get it, what's the difference? How can I run a simple .Net Core App the same way like a .Net Core ASP App?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the "Container development tools" component installed in Visual Studio? You can check by opening the Visual Studio Installer, click "Modify", and see if it is selected under the "Individual components" tab.

Comment: You may also need [Docker desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop) installed if you don't have it already.

Comment: Yes to both. Even with a Asp.Net Core application there are the menu points like "Add -> Docker support" and I can run it in docker easyly

Comment: Weird, mmk. I'm not sure. I have a Core console app that debugs fine in VS 2019 w/docker. If you wanna do any side-by-side comparisons, it's here: https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/tree/master/src/FilterLists.Agent

Comment: Yes indead with VS2019 it works! Thanks @Collin Barrett, please put you answer as a solution and I will close this as working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a non-answer, but it seems to work for Steffen (and myself) in Visual Studio 2019. Maybe there is a bug in the Visual Studio 2017 tooling...